# Complete.obs of cor() function

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, na

I am establishing a correlation matrix for my data, which looks like this

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(56, 123, 546, 26, 62, 6, NA, NA, NA, 15
), V2 = c(21, 231, 5, 5, 32, NA, 1, 231, 5, 200), V3 = c(NA, 
NA, 24, 51, 53, 231, NA, 153, 6, 700), V4 = c(2, 10, NA, 20, 
56, 1, 1, 53, 40, 5000)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This gives the following data frame:

```
        V1  V2  V3   V4
    1   56  21  NA    2
    2  123 231  NA   10
    3  546   5  24   NA
    4   26   5  51   20
    5   62  32  53   56
    6    6  NA 231    1
    7   NA   1  NA    1
    8   NA 231 153   53
    9   NA   5   6   40
    10  15 200 700 5000
```

I normally use a complete.obs command to establish my correlation matrix using this command

```
crm <- cor(df, use="complete.obs", method="pearson")
```

My question here is, how does the complete.obs treat the data? does it omit any row having a "NA" value, make a "NA" free table and make a correlation matrix at once like this?

```
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c(26, 62, 15), V2 = c(5, 32, 200), V3 = c(51, 
53, 700), V4 = c(20, 56, 5000)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

or does it omit "NA" values in a pairwise fashion, for example when calculating correlation between V1 and V2, the row that contains an NA value in V3, (such as rows 1 and 2 in my example) do they get omitted too?

If this is the case, I am looking forward to establish a command that reserves as much as possible of the data, by omitting NA values in a pairwise fashion.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Look at the help file for `cor`, i.e. `?cor`. In particular,

> If ‘use’ is ‘"everything"’, ‘NA’s will propagate conceptually, i.e., a
>   resulting value will be ‘NA’ whenever one of its contributing
>   observations is ‘NA’.
>
> If ‘use’ is ‘"all.obs"’, then the presence of missing observations
>   will produce an error.  If ‘use’ is ‘"complete.obs"’ then missing
>   values are handled by casewise deletion (and if there are no complete
>   cases, that gives an error).

To get a better feel about what is going on, is to create an (even) simpler example:

```
df1 = df[1:5,1:3]
cor(df1, use="pairwise.complete.obs", method="pearson") 
cor(df1, use="complete.obs", method="pearson") 
cor(df1[3:5,], method="pearson")
```

So, when we use `complete.obs`, we discard the *entire* row if an `NA` is present. In my example, this means we discard rows 1 and 2. However, `pairwise.complete.obs` uses the non-`NA` values when calculating the correlation between `V1` and `V2`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have read the help page, I believe I am looking for "pairwise.complete.obs". I wasn't sure though what this sentence means, "This can result in covariance or correlation matrices which are not positive semi-definite, as well as NA entries if there are no complete pairs for that pair of variables". I do have "no complete pairs" in my data (such as row number 7 between V1 and V2) but using the "pairwise.complete.obs" did not show an NA. If you can tell me what the previous sentence means, it would be really helpful. Cheers