# X and Y are inequal length in correlation

Tags: r

I am trying to run a correlation test but must first remove outliers.  The code below yields the following: `x and y must have the same length`.  I don't see where the problem is.  What am I missing?

```
dep_delay<-flights$dep_delay
dep_delay_upper<-quantile(dep_delay,0.997,na.rm=TRUE)
dep_delay_lower<-quantile(dep_delay,0.003,na.rm=TRUE)
dep_delay_out<-which(dep_delay>dep_delay_upper|dep_delay<dep_delay_lower)

distance=flights$distance
distance_upper=quantile(distance,0.997,na.rm=TRUE)
distance_lower=quantile(distance,0.003,na.rm=TRUE)
distance_out=which(distance>distance_upper|distance<distance_lower)

dep_delay_noout<-dep_delay[-dep_delay_out]
distance_noout<-distance[-distance_out]
cor.test(dep_delay_noout,distance_noout)
```

Comment: Do you have missing data in any of the variables? If yes, you can run ```data %>%
                                             filter(!is.na(X) & !is.na(Y))```  
  before the test. I don't think that ```cor.test()``` (check ?cor.test() ) has a ```complete.cases=```  argument, but I guess that ```cor()``` does. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892051/complete-obs-of-cor-function

Answer (score 0):

`cor.test` uses an `na.action=` argument. The default is typically `na.omit` which deletes cases if one has an NA. However your code identifies outliers in `dep_delay` and `distance` separately so the lengths of the columns do not match. Instead of removing the outliers, mark them as NA and `cor.test` will work. Without reproducible data I can't debug a solution, but this should work:

```
flights$dep_delay <- ifelse(flights$dep_delay > flights$dep_delay_upper
       | flights$dep_delay < dep_delay_lower, NA, flights$dep_delay)
flights$distance <- ifelse(flights$distance > distance_upper |
       flights$distance < distance_lower, NA, flights$distance)
with(flights, cor.test(dep_delay, distance))
```

This preserves the row matching so the correct rows can be eliminated.