# Object not found when running cor()

Tags: r

I am trying to find the correlation between two columns (sunshine_in_hours and AgeGroup_30_to_34) from a combined dataset in R. However, every time I try to run the cor() function, I just end up getting this error:

```
Error in pmatch(use, c("all.obs", "complete.obs", "pairwise.complete.obs",  : 
  object 'AgeGroup_30_to_34' not found
```

Here's the dput(head) snipit:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18659, 18660, 18661, 18663, 
18665, 18666, 18667, 18668, 18669, 18670, 18671, 18673, 18674, 
18675, 18676, 18677, 18678, 18679, 18680, 18681, 18682, 18683, 
18684, 18685, 18686, 18687, 18688, 18689, 18690, 18691), class = "Date"), 
    Year = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
    2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
    2021, 2021), Month = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), AgeGroup_30_to_34 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0), Sunshine_in_hours = c(1.6, 
    3.4, 13.1, 8.9, 2, 1.7, 12.7, 11.6, 5.5, 5.6, 4.9, 9.2, 8.3, 
    11.9, 12.4, 12.4, 5.9, 0, 6.3, 8.5, 9.9, 8.7, 6.3, 1, 9.2, 
    6.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.6, 3.6), City = c("Melbourne", "Melbourne", 
    "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", 
    "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", 
    "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", 
    "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", 
    "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne", 
    "Melbourne", "Melbourne", "Melbourne")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried to run the code:

```
Combined <- inner_join(covidS, weatherS, by = 'Date')%>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date),
         Year = year(Date),
         Month = month(Date),
         Day = day(Date))%>%
  select(Date, Year, Month, AgeGroup_30_to_34, Sunshine_in_hours, City)%>%
  filter(City == 'Melbourne')%>%
  cor(Sunshine_in_hours, AgeGroup_30_to_34 )
```

I've tried looking up tutorials on how to do this, however I keep running into a wall. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892051/complete-obs-of-cor-function

Comment: Hi, I've looked at the post, but my problem is that for some reason the function is not recognizing the column names and saying that it is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cor` takes two inputs, and you're giving it 3, two of which it doesn't understand. Try this:

```
Combined <- inner_join(covidS, weatherS, by = 'Date')%>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date),
         Year = year(Date),
         Month = month(Date),
         Day = day(Date))%>%
  select(Date, Year, Month, AgeGroup_30_to_34, Sunshine_in_hours, City)%>%
  filter(City == 'Melbourne') 

corr = cor(Combined$Sunshine_in_hours, Combined$AgeGroup_30_to_34 )
```

Remember when you're using pipes, you're feeding your last object as the first argument of the function you're calling. In this case, your code was equivalent to:

```
cor(inner_join(covidS, weatherS, by = 'Date')%>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date),
         Year = year(Date),
         Month = month(Date),
         Day = day(Date))%>%
  select(Date, Year, Month, AgeGroup_30_to_34, Sunshine_in_hours, City)%>%
  filter(City == 'Melbourne'),
Sunshine_in_hours, AgeGroup_30_to_34 )
```

So both `Sunshine_in_hours` and `AgeGroup_30_to_34` mean nothing if the function doesn't know those are columns from another dataframe. The thing is, this function was coded for base R, and the rest of your programming is `dplyr`, which are different paradigms. Always check the docs when in doubt

Comment: Ah.. I see. Does this mean that the cor() function can't be written within the pipes of Combined in this case? Anyways, this worked, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Exactly! Well, can't is too much, but it would be difficult to do it in a readable way.  
 Functions that easily work with pipes usually have `x` or `data` as first argument

Comment: Ah! I see! Thank you so much again for the help, and I learned something from this. I really do appreciate it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `magrittr` exposition pipe `%$%` instead of `%>%` you could do:

```r
library(magrittr)

dat %$%
  cor(Sunshine_in_hours, AgeGroup_30_to_34)
#> [1] -0.0006941058
```